# Configure nginx with proxy_pass and crowlers with nodejs

Tags: linux, nginx, node.js

I had a problem with my configuration, everything works great except of my crowler proxy_pass, the traffic never touch that server. Is there anyone that know how to get it working with two proxy_pass under the same location / { ?

This is my configuration:

```
upstream play_backend {
    server web01.local:1333;
    server web02.local:1333;
}

server {
    server_name website.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://website.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name website.com;
    listen 443;
    if ($host = website.com) {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.website.com:443$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /xxx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /xxx/privkey.pem;

    #HSTS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    #   ## Block http user agent - wget ##
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (Wget) ) {
        return 403;
    }

    ## Block Software download user agents ##
    if ($http_user_agent ~* LWP::Simple|BBBike|wget|libwww-     perl|wordpress|WordPress/3.9.2|WordPress/4.0) {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://play_backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        #Redirect scrapers to test.website.com
        if ($http_user_agent ~* (googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|developers\.google\.com)) {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.10.2:80;
        }
    }

    location /xxxx2 {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `if($host = xxx.xxx.xxx) statement? Is the `xxx.xxx.xxx`the same host on all occasions you have used it in?

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post, if statement is for the domains comes with none www it should be redirected to with www.

Comment: You should use a separate server block to do that redirect, using if is not optimal for that purpose.

Comment: Can you show me an example ?

Answer (score 2):

i have create a own solution now that actually works and want to share with you guys. The only problem left is to send over the real ip to the upstream

```
upstream play_backend {
    server webb01.local:1333;
    server webb02.local:1333;
}

upstream crawler {
    server crawler.local:8080;
}

map $http_user_agent $backend {
    default "play_backend";
    ~*(facebot|facebookexternalhit/1.1|facebookexternalhit/1.2|googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|developers\.google\.com) "crawler";
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$backend;
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your answer and removed one extra `}` from it.

Comment: worked for my use case +1

Answer (score 0):

It's [recommended](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) to use the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive instead of `if`:

```
map $http_user_agent $backend {
     default play_backend;
     "~*(googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|developers\.google\.com)"
             xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
}

server {
    location / {
         proxy_pass http://$backend;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done that but i get 502 bad gateway and no traffic passed my proxy_pass http://$backend;

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is quite odd actually. There is no `server` block to process `www.website.com`, so it should be processed by the nginx default server.

This isn't related to the original question, but since you asked for an example of redirection from `website.com` to `https://www.website.com`, here it is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    return 301 https://www.website.com;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name website.com;
    return 301 https://www.website.com;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.website.com;
    .... main configuration for the website ....
}
```